# Project Structure. May Angular 2 app folder locates directly in wwwroot?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have faced with 2 different approaches how project structure  may be organized for ASP.NET Core project with Angular 2:

1. create Angular `app` folder in root project folder, and then use scripts/task runners (like gulp) to copy `app` folder content to `wwwroot` folder during deploy.
2. Angular `app` folder can be created directly in wwwroot folder. No additional actions like gulp copy task.

For me the first option was considered as better one, as you have more flexible way to control `wwwroot` final content using gulp copy task. But over last few days I found different examples used second approach. Moreover, the  [aspnetcore-angular2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetcore-angular2) yo generator also places app folder directly to wwwroot and does not use gulp. So what is the best prectice?

Comment: I’ve usually followed the first approach, so I only push actual built stuff into the `wwwroot` folder. That way, the client app source code is very prominently located in the project root too. That being said, Angular 2 continues to move away from easy-to-build processes, focusing mostly on Webpack and even coupling more tightly with TypeScript these days, so it might make sense to touch the deployment process as little as possible; so the second option might be easier. That being said, both is possible and it depends on your personal preferences of how much control you want to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't put stuff into wwwroot directly and it's wise to exclude wwwroot from checking into source code management (git/svn/etc.), this way you can recreate the content of wwwdata depending on your build configuration (i.e. create minimized files or don't minimize for development.

So less junk in SCM, easier publishing since you always start with a clean wwwroot folder when the build/publishing process starts.

For development you can (and maybe should to keep your SCM cleaner), just save the compiled files into wwwroot and only have the TypeScript (*.ts) files in the project's app folder (not inside wwwroot), then you won't need to run gulp tasks after every change to the source code of your files.

There are two options you need to set.

1. `compileOnSave` to `true`, so the *.ts gets transpiled on each save
2. Set the `outDir` to `wwwroot/app` so the transpiled *.js files get saved in `wwwroot/app` folder (and subfolders, relative to your project root)

Here an example `tsconfig.json` I use.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app",
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

This way for development its enough to just save the *.ts files and reload the webpage (assuming your web project runs in the background while you write angular2 code, as there is no need to restart it after every change).

And keep the gulp tasks for build and publishing or to copy over the libraries to wwwroot/node_modules or wwwroot/lib folder.

My project structure looks something like

```
ProjectRoot
| wwwroot
| | app
| | | components
| | | services
| App
| | components
| | services
...
```

Comment: *“it's wise to exclude wwwroot from checking into source code management”* – What about static content/assets?

Comment: Good question, I usually use CDN so I need to know the urls of images etc. in advance. But you can use the same approach as for CSS though, have them copies with gulp once. I use the outDir so I don't have to run the tasks after each change, though that could be monitored via gulp task too  (which you'll have to do anyways if you minimize or concat the files during development too, which is required in large angular2 project as loading 200 files per reload is a pain)